# Selecting the directory underneath cursor in netrw

Tags: netrw

Let's say I am exploring a directory in netrw with many subdirectories:

```
" ============================================================================
" Netrw Directory Listing                                        (netrw v165)
"   /tmp/foo
"   Sorted by      name
"   Sort sequence: [\/]$,\<core\%(\.\d\+\)\=\>,\.h$,\.c$,\.cpp$,\~\=\*$,*,\.o$,\.obj$,\.info$,\.swp$,\.bak$,\~$
"   Quick Help: <F1>:help  -:go up dir  D:delete  R:rename  s:sort-by  x:special
" ==============================================================================
../
foo/
│ dir1/
│ dir2/
...<many directories>...
| dir100/
| dir101/
| dir102/
```

I would like to create a subdirectory in the `dir101` directory. (It is currently empty.) If I press the `d` shortcut, then the new directory will be created in the currently selected directory, which is shown in the second line in the header. In the output shown above it is shown as `/tmp/foo`. If my cursor is over `dir101`, and I hit enter, now `dir101` is selected:

```
" ============================================================================
" Netrw Directory Listing                                        (netrw v165)
"   /tmp/foo/dir101
"   Sorted by      name
"   Sort sequence: [\/]$,\<core\%(\.\d\+\)\=\>,\.h$,\.c$,\.cpp$,\~\=\*$,*,\.o$,\.obj$,\.info$,\.swp$,\.bak$,\~$
"   Quick Help: <F1>:help  -:go up dir  D:delete  R:rename  s:sort-by  x:special
" ==============================================================================
../
foo/
│ dir1/
│ dir2/
...<many directories>...
| dir100/
| dir101/
| dir102/
```

The minor annoyance I am experiencing is that once I've scrolled down to `dir101` the header is no longer in view, so I can't tell which is the currently selected directory. (Especially since hitting enter multiple times will causes the current directory to toggle back and forth between `/tmp/foo` and `/tmp/foo/dir101`.)

My question is if there is a shortcut to select the directory under the cursor without toggling the selection? Or perhaps is there a shortcut to create a sub-directory in the directory currently underneath the cursor?

Comment: One solution might be to consider not using the tree-view. Unfortunately I could not find any variable set (either by vim or netrw) that can be reliably used to know what the current directory is in a netrw browser.